# notepad ++ regex convert query

Tags: sql-server, regex, sqlite, notepad++

Using Notepad++ regex I'm trying to convert a list of queries in such a format

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Name = 'BOB')
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(Name)
        VALUES ('BOB')
END
```

to

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Name)
select 'BOB' 
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Name = 'BOB')
```

I can do the basic find and replace. However, the issue I'm having is getting rid of the parenthesis before the text 'BOB' so I can change `VALUES ('BOB')` to `select 'BOB'`. And if possible move the line `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE Name = 'BOB')` to the bottom.

Comment: [`IF\s*(.*)[\s\S]*(?=INSERT)(.*)[\s\S]*VALUES\s*\(([^)]+)\)[\s\S]*` replace with `$2\nselect $3\nwhere $1`](https://regex101.com/r/1SXgiy/1)

Comment: Show us the regular expression that you have so far.

Comment: what's the point of this?

Comment: @scsimon: I'm relieved that someone asks the question.

Comment: I just didn't get it @CasimiretHippolyte. They accomplish the same thing. By the time someone codes this the OP could probably manually do it.

Comment: @scsimon: however I'm curious about from where comes or for what is this Yoda syntax.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte "Yoda syntax" +1, fantastic

Comment: For those wondering I'm converting sql server stored procedure queries to sqlite queries. This example was more was to see if I can convert the query. Of course I can do it by hand but not so fun when working with hundreds of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use Notepad++ to do a regex Find-and-Replace:

Find what:

```
IF\s+NOT\s+EXISTS\s+(\(SELECT[\s\S]*?FROM\s+(\w+)\s+WHERE\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*([^\)]+)\))\s+BEGIN[\s\S]*?END
```

"Replace All" with:

```
INSERT INTO $2 \($3\)\r\nselect $4\r\nwhere NOT EXISTS $1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Notepad++ Regex Find and Replace:**

**Find what:**

```
(IF)(?<var3>.*?)(\r\n)(BEGIN)(\r\n)(.*?)(?<var1>INSERT .*?)(\r\n)(.*?)(VALUES \(')(?<var2>.*?)('\))(\r\n)(END)
```

**Replace with:**

```
$+{var1}(\n)SELECT '$+{var2}'(\n)WHERE $+{var3}
```

**Info:**

`?<var name>` are back-reference variable names for a block of text in **Find what** which are used in **Replace with** as `$+{var name}`